# Is it possible to train a network based on the output of other neural network in TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to create a neural network that can process the input images for another neural network, say object detection. If possible, I try to take the advantage of TensorFlow Models (https://github.com/tensorflow/models). There are two options that I would like to try:

1. Freeze object detection network (using trained values), only train the first new network. Even though, the training loss function for first network should still depend on the object detection result.
2. Train both networks at the same time, but still keeping the resize operation from the object detection network. The flow would be like this: Input --> first network --> resize to fix resolution --> second network (object detection) --> output.

May I know whether either of the above options is doable? Any suggestion is appreciated.